# Is $z+\overline{z}$ an Analytic function?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

How can I immediately demonstrate that $z+\overline z$ is not an analytic function?

Comment: Because sums of analytic functions are analytic.

Comment: @T.Bongers so basically it means that because of that $\overline z$ is not analytic the sum is not?
and $\overline z$ is not analytic because of CR don't hold?

Comment: @SijaanHallak  T. Bongers meant that if $z + \bar z$ was analytic then also $z + \bar z + (-z) = \bar z$ was analytic, which is not.

Comment: @Ant I see that!  Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cauchy-Riemann equations don't hold. So no. It's not analytic.

$$z=u+iv=2x+0i$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=2\neq \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=0$$

Comment: Thanks!  I needed a simple answer like this ;)

Answer (score 7):

$z+\overline{z}$ is a real non constant function of z. The only real valued functions on $\mathbb{C}$ that are analytic are constant (open mapping propty).

Comment: Thanks!! but I still didnt learn what open mapping propty is.
Going to read about it now

Answer (score 2):

Your function is equal to $2x$ in the real axis. By analytic continuation, it should be $2z$ in the whole complex line. But this is clearly not true.

Answer (score 1):

The zeros of an analytic function are isolated, but the zeros of $z+\overline{z}$ is the whole imaginary axis.

Answer (score 0):

Note that a complex function is analytic if and only if it is holomorphic.
The function $f(z)=z+\bar{z}=2Re(z)$ , but the function $g(z)=Re(z)$ is not holomorphic.

Comment: Up until this moment I thought holomorphic means analytic!! Thanks

Comment: @SijaanHallak which indeed it is :) Did you misunderstand something?

Comment: @Ant I've been taught that holomorphic is a different meaning of analytic..is that right?

Comment: the definitions are different, but one of the most important theorems in complex analysis says that a function is holomorphic iff and only if is analytics (which is want Vincenzo Zaccaro wrote) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analyticity_of_holomorphic_functions)

Comment: @Ant Yeah, I told you I've been taught wrong maybe because we don't need it in our course..
Thanks alot really

Answer (score 0):

One equivalent way of defining analytic is that

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}} =0 $$

or

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}. $$

So since

$$\frac{\partial (z+\bar{z})}{\partial \bar{z}} =1, $$ it's not analytic.
FYI these are some good properties to remember for exams.